# SQL - Select values from a table based on dates using incrementing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a SQL table of dates (`MM/DD` format), targets, and levels, as such:

```
Date     Target     Level 
10/2     1000       1
10/4     2000       1
10/7     2000       2
```

I want to use those dates as tiers, or checkpoints, for when to use the respective targets and levels. So, anything on or after those dates (until the next date) would use that target/level. Anything before the first date just uses the values from the first date.

I want to select a range of dates (a 5 week range of dates, with the start date and end date of the range being determined by the current day: 3 weeks back from today, to 2 weeks forward from today) and fill in the targets and levels accordingly, as such:

```
Date     Target     Level
10/1     1000       1
10/2     1000       1
10/3     1000       1
10/4     2000       1
10/5     2000       1
10/6     2000       1
10/7     2000       2
10/8     2000       2
...
11/5     2000       2
```

How do I go about:

1. Selecting the range of dates (as efficiently as possible)
2. Filling in the range of dates with the respective target/level from the appropriate date in my table?

Thank you.

Comment: `10/1` is 1 October?

Comment: Yes, so from 1 October to 5 November (5 week range). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I got a question, how is that related to the current day?  Do you want to start today and go back or the other way?

Comment: I want to use today's date (on any given day), and from that point, the 5 week range should be: 3 weeks back from today, to 2 weeks forward from today.

Comment: you've got no data in force on 1st Oct I noticed in the example

Comment: For any dates that occur before the minimum date (in this case, 1 Oct comes before 2 Oct, and 2 Oct is the minimum date in the data set), I just want to use the data from that minimum date in the data set.

Comment: I switched to OUTER APPLY in case data is missing for a date (if it is earlier than all entered dates)

Comment: @brodskyb I add sample with categories, give it a try

Comment: @gofr1 Thank you! This seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: @brodskyb my pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you store dates as `MM/DD` but you need some conversion into right datatype. This could do a trick:

```
;WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('10/2', 1000, 1),
('10/4', 2000, 1),
('10/7', 2000, 2)
) as t([Date], [Target],  [Level])
), dates_cte AS ( --this CTE is generating dates you need
    SELECT DATEADD(week,-3,GETDATE()) as d --3 weeks back
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,d)
    FROM dates_cte
    WHERE d < DATEADD(week,2,GETDATE()) --2 weeks forward
)

SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(5),d,101),'/0','/') as [Date],
        COALESCE(t.[Target],t1.[Target]) [Target],
        COALESCE(t.[Level],t1.[Level]) [Level]
FROM dates_cte dc
OUTER APPLY ( --Here we got PREVIOUS values
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) <= dc.d
    ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) DESC
    ) t
OUTER APPLY ( --Here we got NEXT values and use them if there is no PREV
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) >= dc.d
    ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) ASC
    ) t1
```

Output:

```
Date    Target  Level
10/5    2000    1
10/6    2000    1
10/7    2000    2
10/8    2000    2
10/9    2000    2
10/10   2000    2
10/11   2000    2
10/12   2000    2
...
11/9    2000    2
```

**EDIT**

With `Categories`:

```
;WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('10/2', 1000, 1, 'A'),
('10/4', 3000, 1, 'B'),
('10/7', 2000, 2, 'A')
) as t([Date], [Target], [Level], [Category])
), dates_cte AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(week,-3,GETDATE()) as d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,d)
    FROM dates_cte
    WHERE d < DATEADD(week,2,GETDATE())
)

SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(5),d,101),'/0','/') as [Date],
        COALESCE(t.[Target],t1.[Target]) [Target],
        COALESCE(t.[Level],t1.[Level]) [Level],
        c.Category
FROM dates_cte dc
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Category
    FROM YourTable
) c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) <= dc.d
        AND c.Category = Category
    ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) DESC
    ) t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) >= dc.d
        AND c.Category = Category
    ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE([Date],'/','/0')+'/2016',101) ASC
    ) t1
ORDER BY c.Category, d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `outer apply`.  The following creates a list of dates using a recursive CTE:

```
with d as (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, -1, dte)
      from d
      where dte >= getdate() - 30
select d.dte, t.target, t.level
from d outer apply
     (select top 1 t.*
      from t
      where d.dte >= t.dte
      order by t.dte desc
     );
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, if I want to add this logic and use it for multiple "categories" (say that I have another column, "Category", and some of my date-target-level data belongs to category "A" and some of my date-target-level data belongs to category "B"), then I would want "A" to have a 5 week date range (1 Oct - 2 Nov, in this example) AND I would want "B" to have its own 5 week date range (1 Oct - 2 Nov). Any thoughts as to how to go about this? I know I would have to use "WHERE" to specify the category, but how do I iterate this solution across multiple categories?

Comment: what you could try there in the OUTER APPLY is '....where d.category = t.category AND d.dte >= t.dte....'    then order the whole thing by category and date - and add t.category to the main SELECT

Answer (score 1):

you can use a CTE to generate your 'missing' dates, then use a CROSS APPLY to obtain the target and level that was last active (by querying the TOP 1 DESC where the date is on or before current date) - finally I introduced 'maximum date' as a variable

```
DECLARE @MAXD as DATETIME = '20161105';

WITH DATS AS (SELECT MIN([Date]) D FROM dbo.YourTab
            UNION ALL
            SELECT dateadd(day,1,D) FROM DATS WHERE D < @MAXD)
select DATS.D, CA.Target, CA.Level from DATS 
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 Y.Target, Y.Level FROM YourTab Y 
                                     WHERE 
                                          Y.[Date] <= DATS.D 
                                     ORDER BY Y.Date DESC) CA
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

I made a bit of a change with dates to go back 3 and forward two weeks - also I switched to `outer apply` to handle no data in force

```
DECLARE @MIND as DATETIME = dateadd(week,-3,cast(getdate() as date));
DECLARE @MAXD as DATETIME = dateadd(week, 5,@MIND);

WITH DATS AS (SELECT @MIND D 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT dateadd(day,1,D) FROM DATS WHERE D < @MAXD)
select DATS.D, CA.Target, CA.Level from DATS 
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 Y.Target, Y.Level FROM YourTab Y WHERE Y.[Date] <= DATS.D ORDER BY Y.Date DESC) CA
    ORDER BY DATS.D
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Final change - if there is no earlier value for the date - take first future row

```
DECLARE @MIND as DATETIME = dateadd(week,-3,cast(getdate() as date));
DECLARE @MAXD as DATETIME = dateadd(week, 5,@MIND);

WITH DATS AS (SELECT @MIND D 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT dateadd(day,1,D) FROM DATS WHERE D < @MAXD)
select DATS.D, COALESCE(CA.Target, MQ.Target) Target , COALESCE(CA.Level, MQ.Level) Level from DATS 
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 Y.Target, Y.Level FROM YourTab Y WHERE Y.[Date] <= DATS.D ORDER BY Y.Date DESC) CA

    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 M.Target, M.Level FROM YourTab M ORDER BY M.[Date] ASC
    ) MQ
        ORDER BY DATS.D
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm over simplifying this, but:

```
select min(X.Date) Date_Range_Start, max(X.date) Date_Range_End
      , V.<value_date>
      , isnull(X.Target, 'Out of range') Target
      , isnull(X.Level, 'Out of range') Level
   from X --replace this with your table 
   left join <value_table> V --table with dates to be assessed
          on V.<Date> between X.Date_Range_Start and X.Date_Range_End
group by Target, Level, V.<value_date>
```